How to insert data into CUSTOMER
Error 1062 in MySql
CREATE DATABASE temp;

USE temp;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    CNAME VARCHAR(255),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(255),
    GENDER CHAR(2),
    CITY VARCHAR(255),
    PINCODE INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER 
VALUES 
    (1251, 'RAM KUMAR', 'DILBAGH NAGAR', 'M', 'JALANDHAR', 144002),
    (1300, 'SHYAM SINGH', 'LUDHIANA H.O ', 'M', 'LUDHIANA', 141001),
    (245, 'NEELABH SUKLA', 'ASHOK NAGAR', 'M', 'JALANDHAR', 144003),
    (210, 'BARKHA SINGH', 'DILBAGH NAGAR', 'F', 'JALANDHAR', 144012),
    (500, 'ROHAN ARORA', 'LUDHIANA H O ', 'M', 'LUDHIANA', 141101);

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER;


Depending on which query you execute or already have executed, the rows are already in the table. Run only the SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER query to see the content of the table.

Your code is working correctly:
CREATE DATABASE temp;
USE temp;
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    CNAME VARCHAR(255),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(255),
    GENDER CHAR(2),
    CITY VARCHAR(255),
    PINCODE INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER 
VALUES 
    (1251, 'RAM KUMAR', 'DILBAGH NAGAR', 'M', 'JALANDHAR', 144002),
    (1300, 'SHYAM SINGH', 'LUDHIANA H.O ', 'M', 'LUDHIANA', 141001),
    (245, 'NEELABH SUKLA', 'ASHOK NAGAR', 'M', 'JALANDHAR', 144003),
    (210, 'BARKHA SINGH', 'DILBAGH NAGAR', 'F', 'JALANDHAR', 144012),
    (500, 'ROHAN ARORA', 'LUDHIANA H O ', 'M', 'LUDHIANA', 141101);

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER;


Sample Output
I think restart your system and try again


If not then, I think you already created your table, that's why such error is showing like:

So, drop your table and try again 
Drop table if exists CUSTOMER
